# Python multiprocessing hangs on heavy multithreading situation

Tags: python, regex, freeze, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm struggling with a very weird Python behavior I cannot get rid off of.

I created a Python external lib which I imports from inside my main python script. This library receive a huge (up to 50MB) JSON text document divided into sections. I need to parse each one of those sections and extract data with regex.

To speed up this procedure, and knowning the limits of Python not scaling on multicore CPUs, I decided to use the multiprocessing library to create as many processes as there are available core on the physical CPU.

The library splits the main JSON into sections and initializes the different multiprocessing.Process instances passing to each one of the processes a specific text section.

I do this this way:

```
p_one = multiprocessing.Process(
                name=name,
                target=functionOne,
                args=(buffer1, id1)
            )
p_one.start()

p_two = multiprocessing.Process(
                name=name,
                target=functionTwo,
                args=(buffer2, id2)
            )
p_two start()

p_three = multiprocessing.Process(
                name=name,
                target=functionThree,
                args=(buffer3, id3)
            )
p_three.start()    

p_four = multiprocessing.Process(
                name=name,
                target=functionFour,
                args=(buffer4, id4)
            )
p_four.start()


p_one.join()
p_two.join()
p_three.join()
p_four.join()
```

This usually works, however from time to time one of the called joins hangs and it hangs whole main lib - thus preventing my main script from going ahead.

The child processes are not crashing tho, they use Google re2 as regex library and they finish their parsing routine.

As previously said, this doesn't happen everytime, it's very random I'd say. If I kill the whole process and restart it with the same buffer of strings, then it perfectly works, so the regex rules are not wrong nor they are hanging anything.

I tried with the multiprocessing map function, but it was ending up in creating zombie processes and thus I swapped to the multiprocessing.Process.

I also checked with Pyrasite and the blocked thread hangs on the join function.

```
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xxxxx/dispatcher.py", line 401, in p_domain
    p_two.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 145, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 154, in wait
    return self.poll(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 135, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
```

Please do you have any hint/suggestion/something that could help me in understanding why this is happening and how to get this fixed?

Many thanks!

*** Addition ***

This is an example of a piece of code called inside the subprocess.Process() child

```
def check_domains(buf, id):
    warnings = []
    related_list = []


    strings, _ = parse_json_string(buf)

    for string in strings:
        _current_result = _check_single_domain(string)

        # If no result, add a warning message
        if _current_result is False:
            warnings.append("String timed out in DOMAIN section.")
        else:
            if _current_result is not None:
                related_list.append(_current_result)

    related_list = list(set(related_list))

    [...cut...]



def _check_single_domain(string):

    global DOMAIN_RESULT

    # Check string length
    if len(string) > MAX_STRING_LENGTH_FOR_DOMAIN:
        return None

    # Check unacceptable characters inside string
    for unacceptable in UNACCEPTABLE_DOMAIN_CHARACTERS:
        if unacceptable in string:
            return None

    # Check if string contains unacceptable characters
    for required in REQUIRED_DOMAIN_CHARACTERS:
        if required not in string:
            return None

    # Try to match string against Domain regex using Thread with timeout
    thread = threading.Thread(name='Thread-DOMAIN', target=_perform_regex_against_string, args=(string, ))
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()
    thread.join(TIMEOUT_REGEX_FOR_DOMAIN_IN_SECONDS)

    # If a time out occurred, return False that meaning no result got
    if thread.isAlive():
        return False

    if DOMAIN_RESULT is None:
        return None

    # Domain can not starts or ends with a dot character
    if DOMAIN_RESULT.endswith(".") or DOMAIN_RESULT.startswith("."):
        return None

    return DOMAIN_RESULT


def _perform_regex_against_string(string):

    global DOMAIN_RESULT

    # Set result to default value
    DOMAIN_RESULT = None

    # Regex for Domains
    matched = re.search(REGEX, string, re.IGNORECASE)
    if matched:
        DOMAIN_RESULT = ''.join(matched.groups())
```

Comment: what the processes are doing? can you paste a code sample? Also, `p_two start()` without a dot, a typo I hope?

Comment: What is the state of the child processes (according to `ps up`) when the problem occurs? What does `strace -p` say about them?

Comment: @Ashalynd yes, sorry it's a typo when pasting the code.

I just added an example of regex matching function called inside the subprocess.Process

Comment: why do you need DOMAIN_RESULT to be a global? Any chance you get a lock there?

Comment: Hi @Ashalynd nope, I tries changing that logic as well but it doesn't fix the issue :(